# How to close a file when writing is done?

Tags: node.js, file, asynchronous

I'm using the lame package [1] to write some MP3 data into a file. The data is sent as raw audio on a socket and when received its written into a file stream and every 10 mins I write into a new file. The problem I'm facing is that when this runs for a long time, the system is running out of file handles because the file isn't closed. Something like this:

```
var stream;

var encoder = lame.Encoder({
  // Input
  channels: 2,
  bitDepth: 16,
  sampleRate: 44100,

  // Output
  bitRate: 128,
  outSampleRate: 22050,
  mode: lame.STEREO // STEREO (default), JOINTSTEREO, DUALCHANNEL or MONO 
});

encoder.on('data', function(data) {
  stream.write(data);
});

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data) {

    // There is some logic here that will based on time if it's
    // time to create a new file. When creating a new file it uses
    // the following code.
    stream = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

    // This will write data through the encoder into the file.
    encoder.write(data);

    // Can't close the file here since it might try to write after
    // it's closed.
  });
});

server.listen(port, host);
```

However, how can I close the file after the last data chunk has been written? Technically a new file can be opened while the previous file still need to finish writing it's last chunk.

Is this scenario, how do I correctly close the file?

[1] https://www.npmjs.com/package/lame

Comment: what's "data"? Readable Stream or Buffer?

Comment: @KibGzr It's a `Buffer`.

Answer (score 0):

You need process data as Readable Stream then using socket.io-stream to resolve your business.

```
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

//encoder.on('data', function(data) {
//    stream.write(data);
//});

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    ss(socket).on('data', function(stream) {

        // There is some logic here that will based on time if it's
        // time to create a new file. When creating a new file it uses
        // the following code.
        stream.pipe(encoder).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the stream(file) after all write is done:

```
stream.end();
```

See documetation: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

```
writable.end([chunk][, encoding][, callback])#

  * chunk String | Buffer Optional data to write
  * encoding String The encoding, if chunk is a String
  * callback Function Optional callback for when the stream is finished

Call this method when no more data will be written to the stream. If supplied, the
callback is attached as a listener on the finish event.
```

Comment: How do I determine that all writing is done? Writing to the encoder is asynchronously. I.e. adding a `stream.end()` after the `encoder.write(data)` will fail since I'm closing the stream before the data is written.

Comment: I'm probably not explaining the issue very well. The data is written over a period of time. There is no specific `encoder.end` triggered. Image that there are somewhere between 50 and a 100 data chunks written (it varies).

Comment: I think you need use pipe simplify all the things: socket.pipe(encoder).pipe(stream);

You can create your stream class, which will create the underlaying file by time, the encoder and stream will close after socket ended.